# Galaxy Edge 7 edge lighting reminders

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

How would I go about setting a repeating reminder that just lights up the Edge on my S7 Edge?

I have a need for a reminder that just lights up the edge in the same way as it does when the phone is face down and you receive a call (Edge Lighting in Settings).

I have to do something every hour but I don't want the phone to vibrate or make a sound whilst I am in the office do as not to distract my colleagues.

Ideal situation:

- I set a reminder for 9am to repeat every hour
- At 9am, 10am, 11am, etc. the edge lighting comes on with no sound or vibration

Comment: As per this [blog](https://www.google.co.in/amp/gadgetguideonline.com/s7/sasmung-galaxy-s7-how-to-guides/how-to-use-edge-lighting-on-galaxy-s7-edge/amp/) , edge lights up only when selected people call . Is there any other condition under which it lights up? Please mention all events that trigger that to think of a solution

Comment: I'm not aware of any other condition. I can't believe it hasn't been done already though, seems like a *really* obvious feature to add given the capabilities of the device. I don't want to have to write an app, I only need to use it for a few weeks.

Comment: I suspect the answer to this question is "no, not without a 3rd-party tool". Might have to resort to some third-rate Q&A site like Quora if that's the case.... **shudders**

Comment: Hmm..I was thinking of automation since you are talking of hourly schedule but that would mean that the automation app runs on another device and gives you a call every hour. Not convenient, but that's the only idea I have

Comment: Have you checked your alarm app to see if it lights up?

Comment: Yeah, having something call me every hour seems like overkill. Maybe Samsung will read this and add it in their next update package.. Now there's wishful thinking for you :D

Comment: I have checked the alarm app, I added an alarm set not to make a sound or vibrate but it didn't light the edge up unfortunately =\

Comment: Lighting up notification LED seems doable though , but then they may not meet your needs

Comment: Yeah I won't see the light but I can see the Edge... "This awkward bugger.." I hear you say. Well, you're not wrong :D thanks for all your suggestions though :)